# What is the Best Practice for thread-safe access to controls

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

Accessing controls in a thread-safe manner takes longer to code than seems necessary because I have to repeat functions like the following over and over:

```
Private Sub SettbEnabled(tb As TrackBar, value As Integer)
    If tb.InvokeRequired Then
        tb.Invoke(Sub() tb.Enabled = value)
    Else
        tb.Enabled = value
    End If
End Sub
```

I could end up writing one for every method and property of every control.

Is there a more efficient way to code this? Ideally just one sub for the entire app, that I can use no matter what properties and methods of what controls I want to access?

Comment: Bonus points for you, ***what specific programming problem are you having***? All I see is you are wanting opinions which is off topic as it could be broad... Also the reason of throwing the exception is because accessing controls is not inherently thread safe. For example, If you have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is possible to force the control into an inconsistent state or such as race conditions and deadlocks. With this in mind throwing the exception tells you, you ***can't do it*** who cares the way it is shown and or what message is displayed.

Comment: One more last note to answer your question `Is there a more efficient way to code this?`, ***use a delegate*** to make asynchronous calls for the UI which then could call a thread safe method (executed on worker thread) to update what you need on the UI.

Comment: `And for bonus points...` what bonus points are you speaking of?  Thats just a transparent way of asking 2 questions in one post.

Comment: Well, the specific programming problem I was having was that it takes too long to write the code because I have to repeat essentially the same function over and over, which seems inefficient. Thanks for the pointer to the delegate.

Comment: Also consider calling `tb.BeginInvoke(Sub() SettbEnabled(tb, value))` so that the method calls itself again. This way the actual logic of what you wish to do is only programmed once. `BeginInvoke` wont wait for the method to complete either.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi : Just be cautios when using `BeginInvoke()`. Usually you would have to follow up with the blocking `EndInvoke()` in order to not get memory or thread leaks, and though it has been said to be safe to use without `EndInvoke()` _**for WinForms controls**_, I have experienced problems with it that doesn't happen when I use just `Invoke()`.

Comment: The actual control you pass does not matter.  .NET only uses it to find out which thread owns the UI.  Sane way is to pass the form object instead of the control, usually *this*.  Much more sane is to never write code like this, the BackgroundWorker and Task can already do this without the no-idea-what-thread-my-code-runs-on InvokeRequired bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion performing invocation (like you do) is the best practice. I don't think there is a general best practice, but the [**`Control.Invoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`Control.BeginInvoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) methods are used by many.

> Accessing controls in a thread-safe manner takes longer to code than seems necessary because I have to repeat functions like the following over and over
>
> I could end up writing one for every method and property of every control.

Not necessarily, you can still simplify your code in a few different ways. For instance, a [**`TrackBar`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar(v=vs.110).aspx) derives from [**`System.Windows.Forms.Control`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) which means it may be casted into the `Control` class, thus you can generalize the functions:

```
Private Sub SetEnabled(ctrl As Control, value As Integer)
    If ctrl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctrl.Invoke(Sub() ctrl.Enabled = value)
    Else
        ctrl.Enabled = value
    End If
End Sub
```

But there's actually an even simpler way to do it: via [**Extension methods**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx). You can create an extension method that will automatically perform the invocation and the `InvokeRequired` check for you.

Thanks to that a `Sub()`-lambda expression can be casted/converted into a delegate, you can use it as an argument for your method and call it at will:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal Method As [Delegate], ByVal ParamArray Parameters As Object())
        If Parameters IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
            Parameters.Length = 0 Then Parameters = Nothing 'If Parameters has a length of zero then no parameters should be passed.
        If Control.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Control.Invoke(Method, Parameters)
        Else
            Method.DynamicInvoke(Parameters)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

With this extension method, which you can call on any class that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, you will now be able to call for example:

```
Me.InvokeIfRequired(Sub() TrackBar1.Enabled = True)
'Me is the current form. I prefer to let the form do the invocation.
```

By having this you may also invoke longer statements:

```
Me.InvokeIfRequired(Sub()
                        Button1.Enabled = False
                        Label1.Text = "Something happened..."
                        ProgressBar1.Value += 5
                    End Sub)
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I provided the OP with an opinion from my experience, and I also answered his question "Is there a more efficient way to do this?" with not one, but two fairly efficient options!

Comment: You may think whatever you want about my answer. But if you think my answer is bad then at least tell me _why_, because hiding behind the walls of Stack Overflow's voting system is just a coward's behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. Stack overflow can be a harsh place at times but hopefully you'll feel better knowing I appreciate the answer and it's the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: @Nobody : Thank you. I hope it to be helpful! If you have any questions just let me know.

Comment: @Nobody : Was this what you needed? If it solved your problem please mark this as the accepted answer, thank you.

Comment: @dotNET : Perhaps there is, though I saw no better way to put it since AFAIK there is no "best practice". It all comes down to your current needs. You can for instance use the TPL instead of regular multithreading and invoking. -- Thank you for your opinion!